# $W^{2,p}$ regularity of elliptic PDEs with Neumann boundary condition

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Given an elliptic PDE with Neumann boundary condition
\begin{align}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
-\sum_{i,j=1}^N\partial_i(a_{ij}\partial_j u)+cu&=f &&\mbox{in}\,\,\,\Omega, \\
\sum_{i,j=1}^Na_{ij}\partial_j un_i&=0 &&\mbox{on}\,\,\,\partial\Omega ,
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}
in a bounded smooth domain $\Omega$, where $a_{ij}\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ and $c\in L^\infty(\Omega)$, and the following strong ellipticity condition holds for some constant $K$:
\begin{align}
&K^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^N|\xi_i|^2\le \sum_{i,j=1}^Na_{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j
\le K\sum_{i=1}^N|\xi_i|^2 , 
\quad \forall\, \xi_i\in{\mathbb R},\,\, \forall\, x\in\Omega,\\
&c(x)\ge c_0\,\,\,\mbox{for some constant $c_0>0$},
\end{align}

Is there any reference which says that 
\begin{align}
\|u\|_{W^{2,p}(\Omega)}\le C_p\|f\|_{L^p(\Omega)},\quad\forall\, 1<p<\infty \,\, ?
\end{align}
All the references I found are only about Dirichlet boundary condition.

Comment: Does @deMiranda's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37924/elliptic-regularity-for-the-neumann-problem answer your question, too?